# Rewriting permalinks with custom posts

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I've created a custom post type, let's call it 'product'. The site is also bilingual, without any plugins, where I place localised pages under parent language pages, such as:

- English

  - Page 1
  - Page 2
  - Page 3
- French

  - Paginer 1
  - Paginer 2
  - Paginer 3

And so on. This means that my URLs are like `/%language%/%pagename%`, eg `/en/page_1`.

My custom post has bilingual fields for simple localisation but the problem is getting the correct language passed to their public page. For example the page where I list the custom posts exists in all languages and creates a URL like `/%language%/parent_page/%custom_post_name%`, eg `/en/parent_page/a_custom_product`.

The weird thing is that the links work perfectly but WordPress doesn't a rewrite of the URL so that it becomes `/%post_type%/%custom_post_name%/` eg `/product/a_custom_product` and because we've now lost the language part I can't localise it.

I've created a function for the filter `generate_rewrite_rules`:

```
global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%lang%', '(.+?)', 'lang=' );

$n  = array(
    '([\w]{2})/products/([^/])/?'   => 'index.php?pagename=$2&lang=$1'
);

return $n + $r->rules;
```

I've also flushed the permalinks and what not, I'm just interested to why WordPress rewrites the URL and how I can stop it becoming the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear, turns out I need to touch up on my regex, the second match only matches one character. It ought to be:

`'([\w]{2})/the-wines/([^/]+)/?'    => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[2]&lang=$matches[1]'`