# How to change ?lang=cn into /cn/

Tags: url-rewriting, slug, multi-language

I'm trying to add languages to my wordpress driven website and i installed xili-languages plugin. Unfortunately it uses lang param to differentiate between languages and i rather have seen something like http://domain.com/cn/article-in-chinese/ rather than http://domain.com/article-in-chinese/?lang=cn

Comment: If you're not forced to use xili-language, I can suggest [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/) which is a very promising plugin.

Comment: This might help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34810/rewriting-permalinks-with-custom-posts

Comment: Agree with @gyo, Polylang is great, you should try if you've not gone too deep with xili-language. The thing you want is built in with Polylang.

Comment: Another good option would be [WPML](https://wpml.org) (not free though), with which the desired url format is a simple option in the settings

Answer (score 1):

Set permalink to (Post Name)

or

```
http://www.example.com/[blog_name]`/%post_id%/%postname%/`
```

Add following code to `functions.php` of your theme:

```
add_filter ( 'alias_rule', 'xili_language_trans_slug_qv' ) ;


function xl_permalinks_init () {
    global $XL_Permalinks_rules;
    if (class_exists('XL_Permalinks_rules') ) {
        $XL_Permalinks_rules = new XL_Permalinks_rules ();
        add_permastruct ( 'language', '%lang%', true, 1 );
        add_permastruct ( 'language', '%lang%', array('with_front' => false) );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to write:
`http://domain.com/cn/article-in-chinese/`
so that wordpress understand :
`http://domain.com/article-in-chinese/?lang=cn`.

I think it will be easier to use `http://domain.com/article-in-chinese/lang/cn/`. You need to write a new rule and a new tag in WP rewrite rules (Wordpress write those rules in your htaccess) with the functions [add_rewrite_rules()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and [add_rewrite_tag()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag).